# Shutil.copy Won't Copy

Tags: python, shutil

Brand new to programming, diving into it with python and "Learning Python the Hard Way."

For some reason I can not get `shutil.copy` to copy a file. On my desktop I currently have a file "test1.txt" and another "test2.txt". I want to copy whats in test1 into test2.

In another discussion about how to copy files in the fewest lines possible I found this code:

```
import shutil, sys  
shutil.copy(sys.argv[a], sys.argv[b]) # <- I plug in test1 and test2
```

I get the error - **NameError: name 'test1' is not defined**

However, no variation of putting test1 and test2 into a and b runs successfully. I've tried test, test1.txt, setting the test1 variable and then plugging it in, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.argv` returns a list. `sys.argv[0]` contains the name of the script, `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` contain the command line arguments:

```
import shutil, sys                                                                                                                                                    

print sys.argv # print out the list so you can see what it looks like

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]                                                                                                                                                      
shutil.copy(a, b)    # a & b take their values from the command line                                                                                                                             

shutil.copy('text1','text2')  # here shutil is using hard coded names
```

Command line:

```
$ python filecopy.py t1.txt t2.txt
```

Output:

```
['filecopy.py', 't1.txt', 't2.txt']
```

And files `t2.txt` and `text2` have been written. Note that `sys.argv[0]` might contain the full pathname rather than just the filename (this is OS dependent).

Comment: Thank you for the indepth explanation! I totally did not realize that we literally use the numbers in the sys.argv part instead of plugging in our file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `shutil.copy(a, b)` and not `shutil.copy(sys.argv[a], sys.argv[b])`. As evidently the values of `a` and `b` are strings presumably path names and not numbers as one would expect if they were meant to be indexes of the `sys.argv` list.

The following should work if a file or directory named `test1` exists:

```
a = "test1"
b = "test2"
shutil.copy(a, b)
```

Comment: I tried that as well and could not get it to work. If I plug in "test1" or "test1.txt", etc it gives the same error.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Only difference is to do "test1.txt" instead of "test1".